# Is the review queue incomplete as a list of questions that someone has voted to close?

Tags: support, review, closing

I find a question bearing two tags and having two votes to close it.

I go to the review queue and "filter" the search to include only questions bearing those two tags. The queue turns out to be short, and that question isn't there.

Why not?

Comment: I think this is because the question enters the review queue only after some time (it is not instantaneous).

Comment: Of course, close vote is not the only way how a question can enter close votes review - they can get there also if somebody flags them as "should be closed".

Comment: I didn't know that one could filter a search in order to select questions bearing two or more tags. How do you do that?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos go into the close review queue. Towards the top you will see a headline "Review | Close votes" followed by a much smaller  "filter". Click "filter" and follow the instructions. Filter options include tags and close reason. (Similar things work for other review queues too.)

Comment: @quid Thank you. I didn't know that, but that is not what I meant. What I would like to know is how to get the list of all questions whose tags include, say, `group-theory` and `complex-analysis`.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ah, now I think I understand what you mean your point is how to get [tag:group-theory] *and* [tag:complex-analysis] rather than [tag:group-theory] *or* [tag:complex-analysis]. I am not sure about that either, as the latter is what happens if one specifies the two tags I in the field I think.

Comment: I later found the question in the review queue, so possibly one just needs to wait for some time to pass.

Answer (score 4):

Two complementary options are:

- As suggested in a comment by Surb it could be that it is not yet inside the review queue due there being a 15 minutes delay (after the vote or flag), see for example [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284734/)).
- It is already through the queue that is the review was completed yet the question not closed. Note that close-votes take same time to age away even after the review was completed. This would be visible from [the timeline](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/timeline/info) though as you could find a link to the review-report there.

There may be other scenarios I am not aware of but this is what comes to mind.

Comment: Isn't it possible that the question is not in the review queue of Michael Hardy because he already saw the question?  That is, if someone else visited the review queue (without having visited the question first), then perhaps the question would be in the queue?

Comment: Good idea, but I am all but certain that just seeing the question on main does not affect the review queue. Of course if Michael would have skipped the review of the questions earlier (or even had reviewed the question earlier) it would not be shown anymore. But this seems unlikely given the context. Relatedly if it'd be him that had voted  to close he'd not get the review either. So one could expand my list: you voted to close it yourself, or you already reviewed it.

Comment: Thinking about it there may be also restrictions in case of multiple close/open. I'd have to check that. But in any case there are certainly only consequences if a related action was  taken. Just looking at it does not do anything down the road.